# Circle color rotate minigame match problem

Tags: unity, c#

I am creating a minigame that involves rotating colored circles so that the colors match relative to the central circle which is fixed. I was thinking of checking with colliders that the two points at the beginning of one color and the end match with some tolerance to the other circle which also has such collider points set, but I don't know if this is a good solution.
Attached Graphics are only for placeholder purposes and not to scale.

Current rotate script:

```
   public class RotateCircleMinigame: MonoBehaviour
   {
    
       private Vector3 screenPos;
       private float angleOffset;
    
       void Update()
       {
           Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
           if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
           {
               screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
               Vector3 vector3 = Input.mousePosition - screenPos;
               angleOffset = (Mathf.Atan2(transform.right.y, transform.right.x) - Mathf.Atan2(vector3.y, vector3.x)) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
           }
    
           if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
           {
               Vector3 vector3 = Input.mousePosition - screenPos;
               float angle = Mathf.Atan2(vector3.y, vector3.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
               transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, angle + angleOffset);
           }
       }
   }
```

[image: Image 1 - on start rotate]
[image: Image 2 - correct rotates to finish]

Comment: "I don't know if this is a good solution" - well, when you try it, does it work? That's usually a sign of a good solution. It's not clear to me from reading this question what specific "problem" you need help solving. Have you encountered an obstacle in getting your idea to work, or found a bug/unwanted behaviour? Or is the code/setup process excessively onerous in some way? What can we help you fix/improve?

Comment: I have no idea how to implement this reasonably well.

Comment: You mentioned an idea using colliders. Do you feel that approach isn't "reasonable"? Or did you get stuck on a specific step when implementing it?

Comment: Implementing this idea with colliders will not be a problem for me, it just makes me wonder if this is a good idea or maybe there is a better one.

Comment: Then we're back to my first question: Step 1. Implement your collider idea. Step 2. Evaluate how well it works. If it works well enough for your goals, it's a good enough solution and you can move on to the next thing. Step 3. If the solution does not work well enough for your goals, then edit your question here to describe exactly how it falls short, then you can get answers about solving that specific problem you've identified.

Comment: OK, I'll do it :)

Comment: If each circle uses the same sprite, you can also compare the rotation. E.g. `if (Mathf.Abs(rotableCircle.transform.localEulerAngles.z - targetCircle.transform.eulerAngles.z) < 10)` to check if the difference is less than 10 degrees.

Comment: I apologize I'm still drinking my coffee, and may be misreading this, but it seems as though you could consider your center circle to not be rotated, and the outer circles are rotated by some amount. If each outer circle is just the center circle scaled, and rotated, then knowing if they align would just be a rotation of 0, or some multiple of 360. It's no different than if your center circle was rotated, and you're simply looking at each other circle to see if they are rotated the same amount. I'm probably just explaining this the same as @Kevin however